# How to set up scaled axes with hvplot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, hvplot

#### Question:

How to set up scaled axes with `hvplot`? [https://hvplot.pyviz.org/]

#### Code example:

I have the following code giving me the figure hereafter but the lat and long axes are not equal. How to have a 1:1 ratio between the two axes?

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import hvplot.pandas
pos = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('my_gps_positions.csv'))
pos.hvplot.scatter(*'lat lng'.split())
```

Here's the GPS file content:

[image: dataframe screenshot]

And the resulting graph with unequal axes in my notebook:

[image: hvplot with bokeh]

Comment: Just an addition still: maybe this will help you with your geodata and axes: https://hvplot.pyviz.org/user_guide/Geographic_Data.html

Answer (score 2):

You could adjust the **width** and the **height** parameter of the plot:

```
df.hvplot.scatter(x='lat', y='lon', width=500, height=500)
```

Or do you mean the range of the axes? They can be set by parameter **xlim** and **ylim**, for example:

```
df.hvplot.scatter(x='lat', y='lon', xlim=(6, 8), ylim=(45, 47))
```

Since you're plotting latitudes and longitudes you should definitely take a look at geoviews: http://geoviews.org/

Comment: Neither solution give me the same scale on the X and Y axes. What I want is that for example both 1 degree on the Y and X axis is printed out on the screen as being the same length in P pixel or C centimeters.
Thanks for the geoviews lib, I didn't explored it but I will.

Comment: Hi s.k, if you find a good solution to your problem, can you put the answer here?

Answer (score 1):

longitude and latitude units should not be the same distance, except right on the equator.  So normally you would plot these with hvplot as:

```
df.hvplot.points(x='lon', y='lat', geo=True, tiles='OSM')
```

but if you really want to force them to be the same, you can use `aspect`:

```
df.hvplot.scatter(x='lon', y='lat', aspect='equal')
```